# C++ проэкт, VS-2017, почему не находится хеадер

Tags: c++, visual-studio, header

Знаю дуракций вопрос но может всё же поможете.
хеадер `table.h` обьявлен как :

```
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
namespace tensorlearn {
     class Table
    {
    private:
...
}
#endif // TABLE_H
```

в самом файле компилятор не находит ошибки.
в VS проэктах все хеадеры прописываются в фале `stdafx.h`, чтоб во всех исходниках юзать только его :

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

// Headers for CppUnitTest
#include "CppUnitTest.h" 
#include  "table.h"
```

Другие хеадеры находятся нормально, а `"table.h"`  вызывает:
" can not open source file `table.h`". В чём его особенность?
а если я не включаю `table.h в stdafx.h`, то include `table.h в table.cpp` работает нормально, 
в чём особенность этого table.h?

Comment: Магия какая-то. Не бывает. Информации недостаточно. А `table.cpp` и `stdafx.h` лежат в одной директории или в разных?

Comment: все .cpp в source files, хедеры в header files.

Comment: Значит `stdafx.h` и `table.h` лежат рядом, но при этом `#include "table.h"` не работает в `stdafx.h`? Магия какая-то. Не бывает. Вы что-то недоговариваете.

Comment: После определения `class Table` точка с запятой есть? А то бывают неочевидные моменты из-за этого.